# Error installing angular-cli with NPM on a fresh ubuntu install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I just can't understand how to fix these peer dependencies.

I tried to install angular-cli with NPM globally but always results in:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "-f" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0
```

I was thinking NPM was taking care of such version differences.. what's going on?

I tried what I found online: clearing cache, installing with --force, but nothing changes this. I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the same error when i was installing the angular-cli with npm.
but for me version was updated.
1)node v6.6.0

2)npm v3.10.3.

Then after i followed the following steps and the error was solved for me.
Try this,it may help.

1.npm uninstall -g angular-cli

2.npm cache clean

3.npm install -g node-gyp

4.npm install -g node-pre-gyp

5.npm install -g angular-cli

Comment: i hope it will work for you,if same or any other error, let me know

Comment: It did work but especially by updating the npm version to v3. maybe set this to be more precise in your answer for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: last suggestion i think so for this type of error ,                                                you should try to first update all of your global packages

Comment: Actually I didn't notdiced I was running v2, don't understand, this was a fresh install