# Getting permission error while trying to install @angular/cli

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am to install @angular/cli on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer. My node version is
v7.10.0 and npm is 5.0.0

I keep getting this error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-21-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

I also tried the following commands:

```
npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Should I manually try and change the permission or ownership using **chmod** or **chown**?

Comment: are you getting permission denied with sudo?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: @alex-rokabilis Yes

Comment: @suraj Tried that too.

Comment: Me too here, the same error. [This](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) did not help. I tried also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40086371/7576112) 's steps but i am keeping getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It was related to default npm since I had several instances installed on PC.

Currently you're using

> /usr/local/bin/node

Try to find another npm:

> whereis npm

In my case I got

> npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm

Then I tried to use another npm in my installation command:

> sudo /usr/bin/npm install -g @angular/cli

And finally installed it.