# unable to install netbeast-cli with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red, node-gyp

I have recently installed node red and wanted to use [Netbeast for Node-RED](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-netbeast) to follow tutorials.

So I installed it with:

```
npm install -g node-red-contrib-netbeast
```

Then, as indicated on the [github](https://github.com/netbeast/dashboard), I gave the command to install the CLI:

```
npm install -g netbeast-cli
```

but a lot of problems come up,this is ther result:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g netbeast-cli
npm WARN deprecated multer@1.4.4: Multer 1.x is affected by CVE-2022-24434. This is fixed in v1.4.4-lts.1 which drops support for versions of Node.js before 6. Please upgrade to at least Node.js 6 and version 1.4.4-lts.1 of Multer. If you need support for older versions of Node.js, we are open to accepting patches that would fix the CVE on the main 1.x release line, whilst maintaining compatibility with Node.js 0.10.
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.0.17: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: 
//github.com/nodeformidable/formidable/blob/master/VERSION_NOTES.md
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See .........
npm WARN deprecated superagent@1.8.5: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.38
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.16.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET //mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 //mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): //mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@18.16.1 (node-v108 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball //mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): //mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@18.16.1 (node-v108 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http Connection closed while downloading tarball file
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.4 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.4 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.33801.447) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.33801.447) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.16.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp gypinfo spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp  infoinfo  spawn argsspawn   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp C:\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR!  info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.16.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\matti\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.16.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.16.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.16.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\matti\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.16.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 45, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 686, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 678, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 663, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2172, in GenerateOutput
npm ERR!     sln.Write()
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSNew.py", line 367, in Write
npm ERR!     f.close()
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\common.py", line 413, in close
npm ERR!     os.rename(self.tmp_path, filename)
npm ERR! FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Impossibile creare un file, se il file esiste gi�: 'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\binding.sln.gyp.ctqkir2o.tmp' -> 'C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\binding.sln'
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v108-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v108-win32-x64"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\matti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\netbeast-cli\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netbeast-cli\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\matti\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-29T22_41_15_838Z-debug-0.log
```

And this is package installed:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm -g list
C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
+-- formidable@3.5.0
+-- multer@1.4.4-lts.1
+-- node-gyp@9.4.0
+-- node-red-contrib-netbeast@0.0.21
+-- node-red@3.0.2
`-- superagent@7.0.2
```

Can anyone help me?

I have installed the deprecated packages to the latest version, nothing has changed.

I followed the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085880/error-installing-angular-cli-with-npm-on-a-fresh-ubuntu-install) answer without success.